# Why do meteors have different impact velocities?

Tags: meteors

What explains the difference in impact velocity of meteors if they all come from roughly the same distance from the Sun (Asteriod Belt) ? I know the velocity of the Earth itself factors in, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 2):

The Earth orbital velocity is $v_{\oplus} = 29.5km/s$ around the sun. A meteoroid moving in about the same orbit as the Earth has little relative motion with respect to the Earth, and so would fall to the Earth at about the escape velocity from the Earth $\simeq 10km/s$. This is the smallest velocity for a meteor. Escape velocity from the solar system starting from the Earth is $\sqrt{2}v_{\oplus}$ $ = 41.7km/sec$. Suppose a meteoroid comes in from "infinity" on a parabolic trajectory that impacts the Earth in the opposite direction. That would be an impact velocity of $71.2km/s$. Those are the expected ranges for meteoroid velocities